# Objective-C append NSMutableString with commas or dashes

Tags: objective-c

I am appending an NSMutableString like so:

```
[ItemsDesc appendString:[object objectForKey:@"ItemsDesc"]];
```

this is happening in a loop.

How would I add a comma or dash to separate the items ?

Comment: If you iterate in that loop over some `NSArray`, you can instead just call `componentsJoinedByString:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution,

```
for (NSInteger counter = 0 ; counter < COUNT ; counter++)
{
    [ItemsDesc appendString:[object objectForKey:@"ItemsDesc"]];
    [ItemsDesc appendString:@","];   //Or Dash
}
```

And retrieve them back in `NSArray` using,

```
NSArray *strings = [ItemsDesc componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: OP may also find ```componentsJoinedByString:``` useful which allows you to specify an array of strings and get a string back with each of the items separated by a string: e.g. ```[a, b, c, d]``` -> ```componentsJoinedByString:@"'"``` -> ```@"a, b, c, d"```.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending string you can use `appendFormat` method:

`[ItemsDesc appendFormat:@",%@", [object objectForKey:@"ItemsDesc"]];`